# What stops a one-hole kitchen faucet from spinning?

Tags: kitchens, faucet, kitchen-sink

I understand kitchen faucet to kitchen sink compatibility by a simple 1, 2, 3. If I have one hole, I need to get a one-hole kitchen faucet—two for two, and three for three.

[image: kitchen faucet]

As the image above shows, I'm replacing a kitchen faucet that connects through just one hole (of, I assume, a standard diameter).

When installing such a one-hole kitchen faucet, what stops it from rotating around that one hole? It's clear that with 2 or 3 holes the faucet will not spin. Is it merely the case that I need to tighten really hard to make sure a one-hole faucet will not turn during usage?

In case it matters, the faucet has a single handle and a pull-out sprayer.

Comment: I imagine it to be a case of tightness(plus sealer) and/or notches/not round holes.  Most kitchen faucets do spin, but I think you mean the base.

Comment: it is `friction`

Comment: Many (most?) such faucets come with a rubber gasket to place between the bottom plate and the counter, which helps with the friction.